# List for loops in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to count the elements in a list that are greater than element x. Is it correct to use this for loop in C# in order to search through the list:

```
for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
{ ... }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't see how Java is relevant to this question. Please clarify why you are asking Java folks to review this question.

Comment: Yes, that is basically correct. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-for-statement

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with using a loop as you've done, but a better way would be to evaluate the items in your list more directly:

```
var greaterThan18 = list.Where(x => x > 18).Count();
```

This way you don't need a counter as well. Here's how a loop works:

```
var count = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= list.Count(); i++)
{
    if (list[i] > 18)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```